# Removing Backslash from a json file

Tags: python

I have a URL that generates a json file when called. The file is dynamic so the contents change with time. I wrote a code to retrieve the file as follows:

```
page = requests.get(URL)
page1=''
page1='\''+page.text+'\''
page1=page1.replace("\\\"", "\"")
page1=page1.translate({ord('\\'):None})
page1=page1.translate({ord(c): "" for c in "\\"})

with open(FileName, "w") as FileContent:
    json.dump(page1, FileContent)
    FileContent.close()
```

The problem is the file has `\"` where ever it is supposed to contain `"` only (when opened in a json viewer) and i have to remove `\` manually for the json to work. And the above coding don't seem to work. How do we implement this and what is wrong in all the above efforts here?

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by concatenating strings yourself. Create lists and dictionaries, then dump that.

Comment: I didn't get it. New to python and json both. What is wrong here and what is the alternative approach.

Comment: Is `page` already JSON? Then you don't need to do any of this, just write it to the file without changing anything.

Comment: no page is just an auto variable that python creates. how do i do that?

Comment: `json.dumps('"foo"')` returns `'"\\"foo\\""'`. It handles escaping anything in the value of the string that needs to be escaped.

Comment: I know it's an auto variable, but it contains the result of `requests.get(URL)`. Is that JSON ?

Comment: It can be if you do `requests.get(URL).json()`

Comment: Actually, what I really should have asked is if `page.text` is JSON.

Comment: its the link https://chain.api.btc.com/v3/block/latest on this page https://btc.com/btc/adapter?type=api-doc. Please have a look. I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests.get()` returns a response object

If your server returns some body that is JSON, then rather than using `.text`, you should use `.json()`

And then, you don't need to escape/replace anything, just dump that to a file as-is

```
import requests

page = requests.get(URL)
if page.status_code // 100 == 2:
  with open(FileName, "w") as f:
    f.write(page.json())
```

If your server returns escaped JSON text, then you should fix it **there**, not in the client

Answer (score 1):

If `page.text` is JSON, you don't need to do any of this manipulation, just write it to the file.

```
page = requests.get(URL)
with open(FileName, "w") as FileContent:
    FileContent.write(page.text)
```

Also, you don't need to use `close()` when you use `with open()`. The context manager automatically closes it.